# How can i pause the loop iteration based on specific condition

Tags: jmeter

Usecase :- My test contains 5 Thread Group. Each Thread Group is having one loop controller with loop count 2 and all the HTTP requests inside it.I need to execute first loop iteration and pause the loop iteration then execute next thread loop's first iteration and pause until first loop iteration completes of all the Thread Group. The reason of doing that is i need to compare page size in   case of without cache and with cache.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking. It sounds like you want to run Thread Group 1 loop 1, then Thread Group 2 loop 1, Group 3 loop 1, Group 4 loop 1, group 5 loop 1, Group 1 loop 2 and so on - If this is the case, what is the purpose of using separate thread groups? I'm not sure how your requirement of not starting the second loop until all thread groups have finished the first loop is intended to work, or why it's needed. Please edit your question and add more information about what you're trying to achieve, and why.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to have 2 thread groups: one with [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) and another without the HTTP Cache Manager. Remember that the HTTP Cache Manager works only for [Embedded Resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) (images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc.) and given well-behaved JMeter test should have the same network footprint as the real browser - your use case "without cache" doesn't have a lot of sense as I don't think that a "normal" user would disable/clear cache in his browser before accessing next page of your application.

If you still want to accomplish your scenario consider going for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) which can be used to pause other thread(s) even in different Thread Groups while specified condition is met.